# Rspec. Issuing a save on an existing, but modified, activerecord does not run before_update callback methods that are in included modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm starting to attempt to incorporate more testing into my code, but I've hit a wall.

My model looks something like this

```
class Image < ActiveRecord:Base
  before_create :do_something_general
  before_update :do_something_on_update, :do_something_general

  belongs_to :captureable, polymorphic: true

  mount_uploader :image, SomeUploader
  ...
end
```

My rspec looks something like

```
describe SomeModel do
  before :each do
     @image = FactoryGirl.create(:image)
  end
  ...
  describe "moving image" do
     context "change the parent of the image" do
         it "moves" do
            new_parent = FactoryGirl.create(:parent)
            current_file_path = @image.image.file.path
            @image.captureable = new_parent
            @image.save!
            @image.image.file.path.should_not == current_file_path
         end
      end
  end
end
```

When I first create an Image, it will get stored in a file tree structure that depends on its parents. When a parent changes, the Image should be moved, and this is done with the before_update callback :do_something_on_update. My test should verify that when the Image has had its parent changed, it is located in a new location.

The problem is, when `@image.save.should be_valid` an except is returned because :do_something_general is run before :do_something_on_update (the order is important). It seems that the rspec thinks I'm creating a new object (using debugger I've checked that the object id doesn't change when modifying it), and thus runs before_create instead of before_update.

Edit: it seems that before_update is working, but only on callback methods that are in the class, but not in the module. In this case, :do_something_on_update is located in an included module.
End Edit

When I try this in the console in development mode, it works as expected.

Other things to note: I'm using Carrierwave for uploading (the image column is a carrierwave uploader) and when the :image factory is called, it also creates several parents and grandparent objects. Using Rspec 2.10, Rails 3.2.8, Ruby 1.9.3

Looking forward to your responses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `image.save.should be_valid` to fail, because it's going to invoke `image.save`, which returns true or false, then it's going to invoke `#valid?` on that boolean result, which should likely fail.

You might consider writing your test like so:

```
describe SomeModel do
  let(:image) { FactoryGirl.create(:image) }

  context "when changing the parent of the image" do
    let(:parent_change) { lambda {
      image.captureable = FactoryGirl.create(:parent)
      image.save!
    } }

    it "updates the image's path" do
      expect parent_change.to change { image.image.file.path }
    end
  end
end
```

This ensures that you only have one assertion in the test (that the file path is changing), and that if the save fails, it will instead raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are correct in that image.save.should be_valid should fail. I'll make the edit in my question. However, this doesn't solve the problem. I've tried the code above (I had to remove the lambda and its parentheses out to make it work) and got the same exception, which is due to the before_update method not being called.

Comment: Check `image.new_record?` to sanity check it; before_update will be called if it's false. If it's true, that likely means that the initial save isn't succeeding.

Comment: Good idea. `image.new_record?` returns false, which meant my before_updates must have been called. I changed my before_update callback to `before_update :do_something_on_update, :method_in_module, :method_in_class, :do_something_general`. `method_in_class` gets run, but `method_in_module` does not get called. So it looks like before_update will call all the callbacks that are in the class, but not in the included module... any ideas why?

Comment: No idea. I'd never used before_update with chained methods like that, though - I usually have a before_update line per method called.

Comment: In my case, the order of the before_update callbacks is important, hence the chaining. However, even if they are separated out to different lines, it still seems to have the same effect. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Callbacks are implemented as a queue and are executed in the order they're inserted in, so multiple lines should still work. It sounds like you've got some deeper issues happening with the way your models are being built by FactoryGirl, though. Good luck with it!